# Python select last 12 hours new generated files in a folder

Tags: python, sorting, recent-file-list

I am trying to get all files for last 12 hours, file names and the list have following format:

```
C:\myproject\Attendance_aaa_2021-07-22-4hr.csv     07/22/2021 04:20 AM Modified
C:\myproject\Attendance_bbb_2021-07-23-16hr.csv    07/23/2021 16:20 PM Modified
C:\myproject\Attendance_ccc_2021-07-26-4hr.csv     07/26/2021 04:15 AM Modified
C:\myproject\Attendance_ddd_2021-07-26-16h.csv     07/26/2021 16:15 AM Modified
C:\myproject\Attendance_eee_2021-07-26-16h.csv     07/26/2021 16:35 AM Modified
```

This is my code:

```
import os
path_dataset = r'C:\myproject\'

def get_file(path_dataset):
     files = os.listdir(path_dataset) #check file list
     files.sort() #sort file
     file_list = []
     for file in files:
         if (file.startswith("Attendance")) & (file.endswith(".csv")):
              f_name = str(file) 
              tr = '\\'
              filename = path_dataset + tr + f_name
              file_list.append(filename)
                  
     return (file_list)


get_file(path_dataset)
```

However, this code will return all files in the folder. I'm thinking to use below code to identify the file modified time:

```
last12HourDateTime = datetime.today() - timedelta(hours = 12)
```

So that all files with last 12 hours from now on will be listed in my file_list.
Could anybody help with this, how to integrate the time sorting for file list? Much appreciated!

Comment: `os.path.getmtime(path)` gives you the modification time for that file.

Comment: The Python Boolean "and" operator is the word `and`, not the symbol `&`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import time
path_dataset = 'C:\\myproject\\'
twelve = time.time() - 12 * 60 * 60

def get_file(path_dataset):
     files = os.listdir(path_dataset) #check file list
     file_list = []
     for file in files:
         path = path.dataset + "\\" + file
         if file.startswith("Attendance") and file.endswith(".csv") and os.path.getmtime(path) > twelve:
              file_list.append(path)
     return file_list

print(get_file(path_dataset))
```

Comment: Thank you Tim! I tried, however, your code still selects all files. Btw, I have to modified os.path.getmtime(). A minor error.

Comment: I have the inequality backwards.  You wanted files modified LESS than 12 hours ago.

Comment: Thank you Tim! Finally resolved my problem! Just note to edit os.path.getmtime() to improve the answer.

Comment: Interesting; I fixed that shortly after I posted it.  I must have forgotten to save it.